# Insert a new row above and conditional copy to another sheet/tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a [taskboard](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1geeweabJfkcCJDCbFuncxnCdHO5v1olos4QuoYT0YJM/edit?usp=sharing) on a spreadsheet.

---

- I want to insert a new row on the above current row (Row 5) on the current sheet
- **Copy B5 & C5** (Last filled up row, previous row no 5) to **01 (sheet no) if D5=01 (assign to 01)**, and as such as other sheets by clicking the **"Copy & Insert"** button

Please help me

Comment: So what's stopping you?

Comment: Dear @Cooper I'm just learning. :(

Comment: Try reading [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) and [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).  Look for methods to insert row and copy data.  Google Apps Script is based on JavaScript 1.6.

Comment: "I want to insert a new row on the above current row (Row 5) on the current sheet". You want `insertRowBefore(beforePosition)` [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowbeforebeforeposition). To insert a new row before row 5, the method is `insertRowBefore(5)`

Comment: "I want to insert a new row on the above current row (Row 5) on the _current sheet_" Rather than the "current sheet" (whatever that may be from time to time), do you mean the sheet called "Taskboard"?

Comment: 1) Are there supposed to be headers on sheets 01, 02, etc? 2) when the data is copied from "Taskboard" it is to go to the last row, or to the top row?

Comment: Dear @Tedinoz, yes, current sheet=Taskboard, 01,02 sheet title, 2) copied to row 5, and previous data on row 5 go to down row.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. 1) You should edit your question to clarify that the copied data is to be inserted at the top of the sheet rather than appended to the bottom 2) you should edit your spreadsheet to include the headers that should exist on sheets 01, 02 etc.

Comment: @Mahabub What research have you done on your question? There are dozens of examples in StackOverflow, and more in the net itself. Have you written any code to try and resolve your question? Questions that include "Please help me" are often considered off-topic because StackOverflow isn't a coding service. We're here to help you solve your problem, not necessarily solve it for you.

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) on working with Sheets, it should help you out.